SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN while building a mitm proxy server in python
I am trying to build a proxy server in python, which should be able to handle both http and https requests.
This is the code:
import os
import socket
import ssl
import threading
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from OpenSSL import crypto
import datetime
import tempfile

class ProxyHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_CONNECT(self):
        hostname = self.path.split(':')[0]
        cert_pem, key_pem = self.generate_cert(hostname)
        
        self.send_response(200, "Connection established")
        self.end_headers()

        # Write cert and key to temporary files
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as certfile, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as keyfile:
            certfile.write(cert_pem)
            keyfile.write(key_pem)
            certfile.flush()
            keyfile.flush()
            certfile_path = certfile.name
            keyfile_path = keyfile.name

        try:
            # Create SSL context with the temporary certificate and key
            context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
            context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile_path, keyfile=keyfile_path)

            self.connection = context.wrap_socket(self.connection, server_side=True)

            try:
                self.intercept_request()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error intercepting request: {e}")

        finally:
            os.remove(certfile_path)
            os.remove(keyfile_path)

    def intercept_request(self):
        request_data = self.connection.recv(4096)
        request_header, request_body = request_data.split(b'\r\n\r\n', 1)
        
        # Parse the request header
        headers = request_header.decode().split('\r\n')
        method, path, protocol = headers[0].split(' ')
        hostname = path.split('/')[2]
        
        # Create a socket to forward the request to the real server
        remote_socket = socket.create_connection((hostname, 443))
        remote_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(remote_socket)
        
        remote_socket.send(request_data)
        
        response_data = remote_socket.recv(4096)
        self.connection.send(response_data)
        
        remote_socket.close()

    def generate_cert(self, common_name):
        key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048)
        
        subject = issuer = x509.Name([
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"California"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"San Francisco"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"Example Company"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, common_name),
        ])
        
        cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
            subject
        ).issuer_name(
            self.load_root_cert().subject
        ).public_key(
            key.public_key()
        ).serial_number(
            x509.random_serial_number()
        ).not_valid_before(
            datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        ).not_valid_after(
            datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
        ).sign(self.load_root_key(), hashes.SHA256())
        
        cert_pem = cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)
        key_pem = key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
        )
        
        return cert_pem, key_pem

    def load_root_key(self):
        with open('rootCA.key', 'rb') as f:
            root_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(f.read(), password=None)
        return root_key
    
    def load_root_cert(self):
        with open('rootCA.pem', 'rb') as f:
            root_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(f.read())
        return root_cert
    
class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), ProxyHTTPRequestHandler)
    print('Starting server on port 8080...')
    server.serve_forever()


For this I have generated a root certificate, and have installed it in the client's browser, in the trusted root certificates, however I am still getting the following errors
  File "C:\Users\mayan\try4\proxy.py", line 37, in do_CONNECT
    self.connection = context.wrap_socket(self.connection, server_side=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:997)

I am a noob, and have very less experience in this, am I making some silly mistake? Any help would be appreciated.
PS: I am getting this error in the browser
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Browsers don't care about CN (NameOID.COMMON_NAME). You need to use Subject Alternative Names extension instead. Also the browser must trust of course trust the CA which creates the MITM certificates.
